# Fedora php pdo not able to connect sql SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, pdo

installed php7.x while connecting from fedora with the following detail:

```
try {

    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$dbHosts;Database=$bNames", $dbUsers, $dbPasss);
    //Error for this ....ould not find driver

    //$conn = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$dbHosts;Database=$dbNames", $dbUsers, $dbPasss);
    //Error for this....SQLSTATE[01000] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found

    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

i have install all(odbc, mysql) with fedora

where i may have mistake same application with same connection class to same database with credentials works in xampp

regards

Comment: Have you installed the Microsoft PHP Driver for SQL Server? https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql

Comment: i am working in fedora

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a MySQL or Microsoft SQL Database server?

In case of the Microsoft SQL Database server you still need the correct driver for your operation system: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/rhel/

Comment: It's Microsoft SQL